# Selectively show stdout and stderr of a child process

Tags: c++, node.js, stdout

I'm maintaining a cpp application. In this application there are several ways of printing messages.

```
std::cout << "Hello world #1" << std::endl;
std::cerr << "Something went wrong #1" << std::endl;
printf("Hello world #2\n");
fprintf(stderr, "Something went wrong #2\n");
```

If I run this cpp application in console, these four messages will be shown.

Now I have a nodejs application, which will spawn this cpp application. But I can only see the outputs from `std::cout` and `std::cerr`. I assume I have setup the stdio redirection correctly. **But the outputs of `printf` and `fprintf` will be printed when the app is exited.**

```
var child_process = require('child_process')
var cpp = child_process.spawn('path/to/cpp_app', [], {
  stdio: ['pipe', process.stdout, process.stderr]
});
```

If there is nothing I can do on nodejs side, I'd have to change all `printf` and `fprintf(stderr` to `std::cout` and `std:cerr`...

Comment: Did you try it? `printf` prints on `stdout`, so you should receive those strings.

Comment: Buffering and flushing.  You are flushing iostreams (via endl).  Have you tried flushing stdio via fflush()? Next on deck... sync_with_stdio().

Comment: @DavidThomas If I run the cpp program in console directly, all outputs will be shown. Only when I spawn the cpp program in node, I will have this issue.

Comment: @stanleyxu2005. You made the comment that f/printf output is displayed when the app exits. The CRT will flush the output during shutdown. Can you try flushing stdio stream after a couple of fprintfs? `fflush(stdout); fflush(stderr);`

Comment: Yes, as I'm a newbie of cpp. I think I should re-evaluate the case when I should use `std::cout` and when for `fprintf. Please create an answer, I will accept that.